# connect project tango library .so in visual studio xamarin project

Tags: android, c++, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, tango

i am trying to write an app for the Google Tango device using Xamarin in VS2015.  I have created the native activity and put in the basic tango config and connect to service code.  I added the tango libraries in the project settings so intellisense likes it but, the build gives me an error:

undefined reference to 'TangoService_connect'   d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Android3\Android3\Android3.NativeActivity\CCActivity.cpp

the C API comes with a .h and three folder for the various arch's (ARM, x86) containing .so files, and I guess these are not correctly referenced in the settings, how do I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/dannyyy/GoogleProjectTangoBinding

Comment: A very useful link, thanks, but not appropriate to my question as it is a c# package not native code in c++.